# JSON ENCODE in php in two files

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have two files, please refer it.

**v1/index.php (php)**

```
function getuserDetails($request){    
    $userName= $request->getParam('name');
    $mobile_no= $request->getParam('image');
    $email= $request->getParam('email');
          echo json_encode(array('status' => '1','msg'=>'success','data'=>"Name:-".$userName));

   }
```

**index.php (header)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var checkState = function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: './v1/index.php'
  }).done(function(datad){

    var user_name = jQuery('#name');
    var email = jQuery('#email');

      user_name.html(datad.data);     
      email.html(datad.email);   
  });

}

checkState();
setInterval(checkState, 10000);
        </script>
```

**index.php (html)**

```
Name:- <strong><span id="name"></span></strong>
```

I am trying to fetch **name** from other file using `JSON` but it is not fetching, also no error is shown...

Also have a look at [this comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42972233#42972233), may it be more clear for the question

Comment: `console.log(datad)` in your done section and check the console

Comment: Watch your case: `V1/index.php` vs. `url: './v1/index.php'`

Comment: v is small, it was typed by mistake here, cross checked in actual code....

Comment: You're not calling `getuserDetails()`

Comment: Where should I call that function? In script and how?

Comment: At the end of your `index.php` or create a new .php file that calls the function

Comment: Which index file v1 folder Or just index file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173390/discussion-between-raja-and-kerbholz).

Comment: Also have a look at [this comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42972233#42972233), may it be more clear for the question

Comment: "but it is not fetching" - what does that mean?

Comment: Your AJAX is hitting your PHP file, but not that method. There are a few ways to do this. You can have your php file be a script with the methods at the bottom, and have your AJAX hit it with an 'action' payload, such as `{"action":"getuserDetails"}` and have the php call a method based on the action. Or you can set up a more advanced routing system, and have your ajax hit "v1/index.php@getuserDetails", or however that would look.

Comment: @MichaelConard Can you please help me with the updated codes with my codes....